# Nested zip contents listing

Tags: powershell, recursion, foreach, nested, compression

I've been working on a little side project of listing files compressed in nested zip files.
I've cooked up a script that does just that, but only if the depth of zip files is known.
In in example below the zip file has additional zips in it and then anthoer in one of them.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.Filesystem
$path = "PATH"
$CSV_Path = "CSV_PATH"
$zipFile = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Filter "*.zip"
$rootArchive = [System.IO.Compression.zipfile]::OpenRead($zipFile.fullname)
$rootArchive.Entries | Select @{l = 'Source Zip'; e = {} }, @{l = "FullName"; e = { $_.FullName.Substring(0, $rootArchive.Fullname.Lastindexof('\')) } }, Name | Export-csv $CSV_Path -notypeinformation

$archivesLevel2 = $rootArchive.Entries | Where { $_.Name -like "*.zip" } 
foreach ($archive in $archivesLevel2)
{
    (New-object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive ($archive.Open())).Entries | Select @{l = 'Source Zip'; e = { $archive.name } }, @{l = "FullName"; e = { $archive.FullName.Substring(0, $_.Fullname.Lastindexof('\')) } }, Name | Export-Csv $CSV_Path -NoTypeInformation -append;
    New-object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive($archive.Open()) -OutVariable +lastArchiveLevel2
}

$archivesLevel3 = $lastArchiveLevel2.entries | Where { $_.Name -like "*.zip" }
foreach ($archive in $archivesLevel3) 
{
    (New-Object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive ($archive.Open())).Entries | Select @{l = 'Source Zip'; e = { $archive.name } }, @{l = "FullName"; e = { $archive.FullName.Substring(0, $_.Fullname.Lastindexof('\')) } }, Name | Export-Csv $CSV_Path -NoTypeInformation -append
}
```

What I ask of you is to help me modify this to accomodate an unknown depth of inner zip files. Is that even possible?

Comment: You should look into recursion to get around this, create a function that calls itself when it find a nested zip

Comment: I've thought about it, but how would I pass new variables from first to the second iteration of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how to do it using a Queue object, which allow you to recursively go through all depths of your zip file in one go.

As requested, here are some comments to explain what is going on.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.Filesystem
$path = "PATH"
$CSV_Path = "CSV_PATH"
$Queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::New()
$zipFiles = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Filter "*.zip"

# All records will be stored here
$Output = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()

# Main logic. Used when looking at the root zip and any zip entries.
# ScriptBlock is used to prevent code duplication.
$ProcessEntries = {
    Param($Entries)
    $Entries | % {
        # Put all zip in the queue for future processing
        if ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($entry) -eq '.zip') { $Queue.Enqueue($_) }
        # Add a Source Zip property with the parent zip since we want this informations in the csv export and it is not available otherwise.
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Source Zip' -Value $zip.name
        # Every entries, zip or not, need to be part of the output
        $output.Add($_) 
    }
}

# Your initial Get-ChildItem to find zip file implicate there could be multiple root zip files, so a loop is required.
Foreach ($zip in $zipFiles) {
    $archive = [System.IO.Compression.zipfile]::OpenRead($zip.fullname)
    # The $ProcessEntries scriptblock is invoked to fill the Queue and the output.
    . $ProcessEntries $archive.Entries
    
    # Should the Zip file have no zip entries, this loop will never be entered.
    # Otherwise, the loop will continue as long as zip entries are detected while processing any child zip.
    while ($Queue.Count -gt 0) {
        # Removing item from the queue to avoid reprocessing it again.
        $Item = $Queue.Dequeue()
        $archive = New-object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive ($Item.open())
        # We call the main scriptblock again to fill the queue and the output.
        . $ProcessEntries $archive.Entries
        
    }

}

$Output | Select 'Source Zip', FullName, Name | Export-Csv $CSV_Path -NoTypeInformation
```

**References**

[Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Nicely done, I was unaware `[ZipArchive]::new($entry.Open())` was needed for nested `.zip` files, I tested using only `[ZipFile]::OpenRead(..)` on Linux and it worked fine, seems like it was changed on .NET Core?

Comment: This indeed does what I want. Thank you. Would you be willing to brek it into parts and explain? I have never before dealt with queue objects and lists.

Comment: @nawad-sama Good to know. I am away from the computer but I will come back and expand on the specific mechanics at play here when I get back.

Comment: Thank you for this. Really.  I think I figured most of it out. I have a some questions though.
Is there an advantage in using `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($entry) -eq '.zip'` instead of ` `Where { $_.Name -like "*.zip" }` ?
Is `$Item` a variable specific to `[System.Collections.Queue]` or is it there just to use `Dequeue()` method?

Comment: @Nawad-sama There might be a slightly different performance between the 2 if you have a huge number of entries although I did not test that. For most practical purposes, using `if ($_.name -like '*.zip'` will probably be undistinguishable. `$Item` is indeed just to store the element we dequeued and unrelated to the Queue object. You could have used a list instead of a Queue but since the process here is clearly a queue process by its nature (First-in / First-out), I chose this object.

Comment: As for the list, rule of thumb, you mostly never want fixed arrays `@()` and `+=` is to proscribe since it recreate a new array every time. Hence the use of lists to have a dynamically sized collection that can grow without performance impact.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I did not give much attention to the ZipFile / ZipArchive part at all. There might be a better way to do it, but since this was not the focus of the question and also that I do not work much with zip files, I did not look at it further. I just made sure it worked and devised a recursive loop around it.

Comment: Wow, a very comprehensive explanation. Thank you again. Now I understand everything

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a little example of how recursion would look like, basically, you loop over the `.Entries` property of `ZipFile` and check if the extension of each item is `.zip`, if it is, then you pass that entry to your function.

**EDIT:** Un-deleting this answer mainly to show how this could be approached using a *recursive function*, my previous answer was inaccurate. I was using `[ZipFile]::OpenRead(..)` to read the nested `.zip` files which seemed to work correctly on Linux (.NET Core) however it clearly does not work when using Windows PowerShell. The correct approach would be to use `[ZipArchive]::new($nestedZip.Open())` as [Sage Pourpre's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71159432/15339544) shows.

```sh
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.IO.Compression

function Get-ZipFile {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [object]$Path,
    [parameter(DontShow)]
    [int]$Nesting = -1
)
    begin { $Nesting++ }
    process {
        try
        {
            $zip = if(-not $Nesting) {
                [ZipFile]::OpenRead($Path)
            }
            else {
                [ZipArchive]::new($Path.Open())
            }
            foreach($entry in $zip.Entries) {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Nesting = $Nesting
                    Parent = $Path.Name
                    Contents = $entry.FullName
                }
                if([Path]::GetExtension($entry) -eq '.zip') {
                    Get-ZipFile -Path $entry -Nesting $Nesting
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
        }
        finally
        {
            if($null -ne $zip) {
                $zip.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem *.zip | Get-ZipFile
```